# foreach loop submit button

Tags: php, foreach

I have listed my data results using a foreach loop. And as you can see within the foreach loop there is an accept as well as a delete button for each data result.

Even if I clicked first result's 'accept button' the second data result was updated in first result database. Therefore I made ids on each button. After the changes the buttons are not working.

**So basically what I want to do is, when I click first result's 'accept button', first result will be saved in the database in proper position.**

```
<?php 
foreach($getC  as $iden => $row)
{
    echo '<div class="form-group">';
    echo '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nameinput">C Name : '.$row['cName'].'</label>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="form-group">';
    echo '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nameinput"><b>CAName : '.$row['CaName'].'</b></label>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="form-group">';
    echo '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nameinput"><b>C Description : '.$row['CD'].'</b></label>';
    echo '</div>';  
    echo '<div class="form-group">';
    echo '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nameinput"><b>Outer C : '.$row['regionAbb'].'</b></label>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="form-group">';
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='id2' value='$iden'>";
    echo '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submitbutton"></label>';
    echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
    echo '<button name="accept'.$iden.'" class="btn btn-primary">Accept</button>';
    echo '&nbsp <button name="decline'.$iden.'" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';  


}
$Abutton = "accept".$_POST["id2"];
$Dbutton = "decline".$_POST["id2"];
    if(isset($_POST[$Abutton]))
{
    mysqli_query($conn, "Update user SET UserIC = '$row[CName]' WHERE username= '$row[CAName]'");
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Request has been accepted.")';
    echo '</script>';   

}
else if(isset($_POST[$Dbutton]))
{
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Request has been declined.")';
    echo '</script>';   

}   
?>
```

Comment: Create a `<form>` for each entity

Comment: Thank you for reply fast. but what do you mean by creating form for each entity? does it mean, I should put <form> for each buttons?

Comment: For each group of fields

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value of the submit type, to do what you want, for example, if you want multiple submits, to diferentiate them:

```
<input class="button" align="right" type="submit" value="actiontobutton1"  name="sub" >
<input class="button" align="right" type="submit" value="actiontobutton2"  name="sub" >
```

Then, in PHP you can read that value with:

```
if($_POST["sub"]=="actiontobutton1"){//dothingshere}
if($_POST["sub"]=="actiontobutton2"){//dothingshere2}
```